# Airflow database querying

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, airflow

I am having a flask application which uses airflow data.I would like to access the airflow database from my flask application and query the data.I am able to run raw SQL query.But i should have a solution how to use SQL alchemy query technique in it. For example if i need the dag table data. I should be able to run `Dag.query.all()` to get all dag data.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow uses [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (currently [1.1.x](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/26e0d449737e8671000f671d820a9537f23f345a/setup.py#L300) for the Airflow 1.10 trunk) to manage its models, so you can interact with and query them using the standard SQLAlchemy API as documented in the tutorial.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/tutorial.html

You can access your database using a standard database connection string from any Python code, such as your Flask app, as described in the above tutorial as well.

There are examples of various the database connection URL formats supported by `create_engine()` here.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/engines.html#database-urls

You can find more info such as the fields on a particular model in Airflow's models.py file.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py

You can find more SQLAlchemy documentation here.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/